# Large term sets in SharePoint 2010

Tags: managed-metadata

Is there a best practice, or limit regarding the maximum number of items in a term set?

I did a quick test, and imported 50,000 items using the import tool (all items with the same parent).

I got an error during upload, and when I looked at the resulting term set only 9996 items was imported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1000 Term Sets per Term Store, and a further 1 million terms per Term Set are the max values. What error did you get?

Comment: Thanks. You may find the dummy data and logs here: http://cid-5d0909fd6cd506a0.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/TermstoreTest?uc=1 The correlation ID was 580697a2-1a8a-464d-a704-fc48bb250a09.